# robot_localization dual-EKF: where did the idea come from?

Tags: navigation, ekf, gps, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're currently using the dual-EKF scheme described in the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html) and the [configuration example](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/melodic-devel/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml)  for using two instances of robot_localization: one for estimating the map->odom transformation, and another for odom->base_link transformation. So far, it's a working pretty well. My question: who invented this scheme? Is it common practice for UGV localization, and if yes, is there some literature out there about it? I haven't had any luck turning up a paper that talks about the pros/cons of this technique.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312006/robot_localization-dual-ekf:-where-did-the-idea-come-from?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2019-01-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2019-01-07**:
I guess that would be a good question for @Tom-Moore to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's all really just a reflection of what's specified in [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). From the "Frame Authorities" section:

> The transform from odom to base_link is computed and broadcast by one of the odometry sources.

> The transform from map to base_link is computed by a localization component. However, the localization component does not broadcast the transform from map to base_link. Instead, it first receives the transform from odom to base_link, and uses this information to broadcast the transform from map to odom.

The whole REP is worth a read. I haven't updated `r_l` to work with the changes involving the *earth* frame, but I believe it conforms to the rest.

Note that you don't *have* to have a dual EKF setup. It's just that if you want your state estimate to come from fused data, rather than a single data source, then `r_l` can support that. Other approaches, such as letting `amcl` handle the *map* frame state estimate (and transform publication) by itself, or letting your wheel encoder odometry source (e.g., the differential drive controller) provide the *odom* frame state estimate/transform by itself, will also work.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3